# Error when trying to use toast in android application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

in my application i am fetching json data from online server. and after that i am trying to display the data by toast. but the application stop working. if i commented the toast section then the application runs smoothly. so i think there is a problem in toast section. so guys plz help me to find out the reason for the problem

```
   package com.example.getdata;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;





import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText password,username;
    String pass,user;
    //TextView output;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }


    public void onConnect(View v) {




         new Thread(){
             public void run(){
                 HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                 HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://tusharinfotech.com/debasish/get_data.php");
             try {
                     List<NameValuePair> myArgs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    // myArgs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user));
                    // myArgs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));
                     post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(myArgs));
                     HttpResponse myResponse = myClient.execute(post);
                     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(myResponse.getEntity().getContent()));
                     String line = "";
                     String data1 ="";
                     while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                     {
                         try {
                            JSONArray myarray = new JSONArray(line);
                            for(int i=0;i<myarray.length();i++){
                                JSONObject jsonObject = myarray.getJSONObject(i); 
                                int id = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.optString("FOOD_ID").toString());
                                String name = jsonObject.optString("FOOD_NAME").toString();
                                data1 += "Node"+i+" : \n id= "+ id +" \n Name= "+ name +" \n ";  
                            }

                        //Log.d("mytag",data);
                            //this application stop working for this toast part.. if i commented it then the application run smoothly
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),data1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                         //EditText output1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                        // output1.setText(data);
                         Log.d("mytag", line);

                     }
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
             }
         }.start();

     }



}
```

Comment: I can guess what the problem is but for more info please post your logcat

Comment: You cant update the UI from the background thread

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you are trying to show toast on a background thread, which is not allowed in android. you can use this code to show toast in background thread :

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: place it instead of this line : Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),data1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: it's showing error " activity cannot resolved". how to fix it

Comment: try using getApplicationContext() instead of activity, I edited the answer ;)

Comment: or you can add 'Activity activity = this;' in first line of your class, blow this line 'public class MainActivity extends Activity {...'

Comment: ok.. but stil there is problem in another line . "activity.runOnUiThread" there is also displaying activity cannot resolved error msg

Comment: check my previous comment, you must create field "activity" in you activity

Answer (score 0):

You must display Toast only from UI thread, to workaround this you can get use of runOnUiThread() method or create new Handler and pass in  constructor Looper.getMainLoopper()

Answer (score 0):

You could use AsyncTask Framework to make background processing easier http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html.
The method `onPostExecute(Result)` will be run on your UI thread there for you can change your UI element here.